# Selenium Webdriver Set up

Tags: selenium, amazon-web-services, windows-10

I'm not sure its a Selenium OR Windows OR AWS question.

Here is what I'm looking for

I am trying to configure **Selenium WebDriver 2.41.0 + Chrome driver 2.24**, with Windows 10 nodes in AWS.

I've created a batch file to start selenium node, and added the batch file in startup

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

But when I try to restart the node, the batch file doesn't start by itself unless and until I login to this machine physically. Logging in to each machine is not practically possible, there are around 80 node machines.

Tried creating a new task task in task scheduler and enabled "Run whether the user is logged on or not" but didn't work.

Can any one help?

Comment: Well it is definitely not a batch-file question.

Comment: *didn't work* what does that mean? How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: thanks for the response, the reason I say it didn't work is, I tried checking the http://<IP>:4444/grid/console, and I coudn't see the registed machine listed there. But when I logged in manually to that machine, and I could see the batch file triggered and then this machine got listed in the console

Comment: Sorry I missed to answer to your first question, "didn't work" means, the batch file didn't get executed with the boot. I had to manually login to the machine to get the batch file executed.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dawogfather.github.io/vagrant-aws-selenium/) might help.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but that's not really helping much :(

Comment: How do you know that it didn't get executed (it will be invisible). What does added it to startup means. There are many ways of autostarting programs. How did you add it, with what settings? Edit your question with details. This is basic.